# Integrate doc visualizer at DSpace instance

Tags: dspace

I want to integrate a document visualizer at a DSpace setup that I have already running locally in my pc.
I've found this solution https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSPACE/Document+Preview+with+Google+Docs+viewer but I'm not so good with Java and want to make sure to do it fine and not breaking what I've already had.

Comment: You did not state what version you're running and what interface (JSPUI or XMLUI). Unfortunately, it is stated from that page, it won't work if your instance is running locally (Google can't reach it).

Comment: @euler You are right. I'm running 6.3 version with JSPUI interface. But if you say that won't run locally I'm probably wasting my time.

Comment: Do you know if I can place a PDF and IMG viewer an any guidance to achieve that?

Comment: Please check: [Document Viewer Integration](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSPACE/Document+Viewer+Integration). Please note that I have only tried FlexPaper and Google Docs.